# How to call a blocking service from my Reactive REST with Quarkus/Mutiny

Tags: quarkus, reactive, mutiny

I need to call service B after service A has finished and need the return value from service A to be used on service B.
How do I do this? Can you guys help me?

My code below is not working properly, Service B/productService.checkout is not executing.

```
public Uni<List<Shop>> checkout(Person person) {
     Uni<List<Shop>> shopsUni = shopService.find("person_id", person.getId()).list();
        return shopsUni.map(shops -> {
            for (Shop shop : shops) {
                productService.checkout(shop);
            }
            return shops;
      });
}
```

Comment: I assume `productService` is blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `chain` operator, as you want to *chain* the call to service A with the call to service B. So, you will need something like:

```java
public Uni<List<Shop>> checkout(Person person) {
   // Represent the call to the Service A
   Uni<List<Shop>> shopsUni = shopService.find("person_id", person.getId()).list();

   return shopsUni.chain(shops -> {
       // Here is a small subtility. 
       // You want to call the Service B multiple times (once per shop), 
       // so we will use "join" which will call the Service B multiple times
       // and then we _join_ the results.
       List<Uni<Void>> callsToServiceB = new ArrayList<>();
       for (Shop shop: shops) {
           // I'm assuming productService.checkout returns a Uni<Void>
           callsToServiceB.add(productService.checkout(shop)); 
        }
        // Now join the result. The service B will be called concurrently
        return Uni.join(callsToServiceB).andFailFast()
            // fail fast stops after the first failure. 
            // replace the result with the list of shops as in the question
            .replaceWith(shops);    
    });    

}
```

Comment: Yes it worked for me, with a return like this

***return Uni.join().all(callsToServiceB).andFailFast()
                     .replaceWith(shops);***

Thank you very much sir @Clement